# Passing an NSArray into a realm query objectsWhere

Tags: ios, performance, realm

I'm using realm in my project to store objects, but in this case, I need a specific query. I have an array filled with IDs, and after some operations, I need to get all the object with one of these ID and other specific conditions.

At the moment I need to do this query, I have this data (the array of IDs is filled dynamically):

```
    NSArray *IDs = @[@(1203), @(2421), @(3034), @(2024)];
    NSString *predicateString = @"isSongFromCatalog = 1 && researchScore > 0";
    RLMResults *result = [KFSong objectsWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString]];
```

So, how can I add a condition in my predicate to get only the objects which have an ID contained in this array?

In SQL, it will be equivalent to a request like that to check with the array:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID IN (IDs);
```

I already tried to construct an predicate with all the ID, but this solution is really expensive and no optimise... I also try to use the keyword `ANY` but I don't have a RLMArray to do it. So, I'm running out of ideas. Is there any equivalent to `IN`?

Comment: One more note, to save yourself trouble down the line, don't use NSString to create predicates, just use NSPredicate itself. NSPredicate has special abilities to strip and escape weird characters, where as NSString is very literal so it can cause bugs easily

Comment: In completion, this is a useful article for anyone using predicate and realm: http://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation available on Realm Website, you can find :

> See Apple’s Predicates Programming Guide for more information about building predicates. Realm supports many common predicates:
>
> The containment operand IN such as name IN {‘Lisa’, ‘Spike’, ‘Hachi’}
>   Nil comparisons ==, !=, e.g. [Company objectsWhere:@”ceo == nil”].
>   Note this only works for objects with relationships, for example here,
>   ceo is a property on the Company model.

Is that what you've been looking for?